# How to determine if the kernel sources are installed?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, compiling

I just bought a USB 3.0 Gigabit ethernet adapter. It uses an ASIX ax88179_178a driver.

I need to build the driver and the readme says:

> ...you need the Linux kernel sources installed on the build machine, and make sure that the version of the running kernel must match the installed kernel sources.

How do I know if I have the kernel sources installed?

I installed LMDE 2, 64-bit Mate desktop.

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in? The driver might already be installed.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. It keeps trying to request an IP.

Comment: That's a different issue. In this case, your kernel already has the driver. Run `modinfo ax88179_178a` to see info about the driver and `lsmod | grep ax88179` to show that the driver has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, looks good for both commands. Don't have room to display the results though. So, the driver looks like it compiled and loaded. Unfortunately, my usb ethernet adapter still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm saying you already have the driver; you don't need to build the driver again.

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately, I followed the instructions and built the driver before checking if it was already installed. Well, since it didn't work prior to checking, I'm pretty sure I would have followed through with instructions anyways, if I did check.

Answer (score 0):

Follow further instruction on the readme file:

Mount driver and go to the driver directory and execute:

```
[root@localhost template]# modprobe usbnet   
[root@localhost template]# insmod ax88179_178a.ko
```

If you want to unload the driver:

```
[root@localhost anywhere]# rmmod axax88179_178a
```

or permanently:

```
[root@localhost template]# make install
```

I did not have to compile anything, the .ko file was generated automatically, I just had to mount the driver and it worked! I was afraid to change the kernel manually but it wasn't necessary.